# The plugin does not have a valid header on activate plugin by code

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to unzip more than 2 folders in plugin folder by word press functions, and i got succeed to do that and with extraction of the plugin i wanted to activate that so i used activate_plugin() function, but getting `The plugin does not have a valid header` error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your header, there are some characters like $ : % / & or , like:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Simple:Press & % $


*/
?>
```

Try to remove that, and then activate again. Also, try by installing both plugins manually. You might be able to find one which is causing this issue.

Comment: don't have special character. And i cant install plugin manually cause i am creating a package with specific plugins which is install and activate on theme ativation.